# Can I install apache webserver inside a company VPN machine, so, that only the machines inside VPN can be served?

Tags: vpn, apache-http-server

The scheme is that one of the machines logged in the VPN network has the Apache server, and the other machines logged in the VPN network can reach it, no outside access is allowed.

Comment: It should be as simple as connecting both the server and the client to the VPN.  This assumes that the Apache server is configured to respond to traffic on the VPN, by default, Apache is configured to response to specific network configuration (local host, a specific intranet address, or a specific domain or public ip address).

Comment: Thank you Ramhound. And how to configure Apache so?

Comment: That is an extremely broad subject that is well documented

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, I will look after.